# Generate a password list file

Tags: passwords, generator, combinations

Well met!

I'm unfortunately not a programmer, but I need some help in order to solve a great mystery of mine. I want to generate all combinations of an 8 character long string with regards to the alphabet, numbers 0-9 and the size of all the letters. The plain truth is that I want to access an old encrypted volume for which I've forgotten my password. However, I know it's 8 characters long (yeah, unsecure), and I know that I used a combinations of numbers and letters of all sizes.

Any pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If your password is 8 characters long, and can contain 26 all lower case or all upper case letters plus 10 digits, then you would be looking at (26 + 10) ^ 8 = 2,821,109,907,456 combinations.  You might be able to crack it provided you can programatically acess it at something like 500 million tries per second.  That would not take more than 2,821,109,907,456 / 500,000,000 = 5,643 seconds - which is a little less than an hour and a half.  If however you mean both upper case and lower case letters, then the number of combinations escalates to (26 + 26 + 10) ^ 8 = 360,040,606,269,696 combinations and would take roughly 128 times longer or 5,643 * 128 = 722,304 seconds.  Since there are 86,400 seconds in a a day, dividing 722,304 by 86,400 yields 8.36 days.  That is assuming you can feed it strings containing the password that fast.

Anything you can do to try and remember a portion of the password would be helpful.  If you must enter the password manually, then it is not solvable.  If you have an old computer or old hard drive, then try looking around on it for the password or perhaps a hint for the password that would allow you to reconstruct it.  Did you ever send the password in an email or email attachment to someone?  If so, you might be able to retrive it that way.  Could you possibly have written it down somewhere?  Where would that be if you had?  Does the password you selected have a special meaning such that if you remember one or two digits, you can figure out the rest of the password from that?